# List used images from Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to distribute a Docker Compose system as a single archive. For this I want to run `docker save` on all the images. But how do I get the list of images from Docker Compose?

This is what I do at the moment:

```
IMAGES=$(cat docker-compose.yml | sed -n 's/image:\(.*\)/\1/p')
docker save -o images.tar $IMAGES
```

Comment: Seems as good a way as any, there's nothing built-in to do this. What's the use for wanting to distribute a single archive? (seems kind of hacky 'tis all).

Comment: I want to deploy it on a machine not connected to the Internet. Is there a nicer way to do that?

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `docker compose convert`. This is helpful, as it will expand any environment variables used to define your images in the compose file.

```bash
IMAGES=( $(docker compose convert --images) )
docker save ${IMAGES[@]} | gzip > images.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
# Save Compressed Images
IMAGES=`grep '^\s*image' docker-compose.yml | sed 's/image://' | sort | uniq`

docker save $IMAGES | gzip > images.tar.gz

# Load Compressed Images
gunzip -c images.tar.gz | docker load
```

Comment: This is not working for neither local `build` images and `extends`-ed from services.